# SQL Server Select data excluding Junction table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to select data that is not present in the junction table 
so got three tables

trialsTable (trialID,TrialName)
VolunteerTAble(volunteerID, VolunteerName)
JunctionTAble(JunctionTableIs,TrialID,VolunteerName)

for every trial an email is sent to volunteers, but next time i want to exclude the volunteers which have received email for that trial and only send email to volunteers which have not received email for that trial, hence i created the junction table which have many to many relationship for the trial and volunteers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a variable or something for the @TrialId which you currently want something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM VolunteerTable v
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                    FROM JunctionTable j 
                   WHERE j.VolunteerName = v.VolunteerName 
                     AND j.TrialID = @TrialId)
```

And you should probably put volunteerID in you juntion table instead of name.

Comment: Karl, agreed i meant to write volunteerID in junction table, and thanks for solution, but why select 1 in the sub query why not select *

Comment: @GROVER_SYAAN: It's habitual microoptimization. The query optimizer will expand SELECT * to the column list to figure out it doesn't need any of them. SELECT 1 avoid that tiny bit of work. Past that point performance would be the same. [See http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/exists-subqueries-select-1-vs-select/ for every so slightly more detail.]